# Liquibase - uploading many Oracle triggers in one file

Tags: oracle, triggers, liquibase

I have a number of Oracle triggers stored in a file which we upload to our DB using sqlplus. We want to use liquibase instead to manage this, but I don't really want to split out the triggers into separate files. The file looks like:

```
  create or replace trigger Trig1 ...
  ...
  end Trig1;
  /
  create or replace trigger Trig2 ...
  ...
  end Trig2;
  /
  ...etc.
```

I've tried

```
<sqlFile splitStatements="true" endDelimiter="/" path="triggers.sql">
```

but it still seems to be trying to split on ';'. If I change splitStatements to false. it then ignores the '/' and includes everything as an invalid single trigger.
Any ideas?

TIA.

Comment: Why don't you want to split `triggers.sql` into separate files?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old issue and OP has  moved on, but for anyone else I ended up finding the answer here: http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/oracle-end-delimiter-issue.

It turns out "endDelimiter" is a regular expression -- this string should be used:

```
\n/\s*\n|\n/\s*$
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This totally worked for me, putting a large initial schema script in a plain .sql file and calling it from a changeset tag with a <sqlFile tag like this:  `<sqlFile path="db/20131022-initialSchema.sql" splitStatements="true" endDelimiter="\n/\s*\n|\n/\s*$"/>`

Answer (score 3):

I recently got this issue. endDelimiter should be:

```
endDelimiter="(?m)^/$"
```

Comment: Superb! This is a MUCH cleaner version of working delimiter! Big thanks! P.S. To use it in raw SQL change sets you must specify it without quites: endDelimiter:(?m)^/$

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with Oracle 11g and Liquibase. I get an ORA-00911.
In my db-changelog.xml I point to a sql file where I have triggers. This does not work at all. I have tested the things you said above with /\;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADRESSE_ID_TR 
            BEFORE INSERT ON ADRESSE 
            FOR EACH ROW 
            WHEN (new.ID IS NULL) BEGIN 
            SELECT adresse_seq.NEXTVAL 
            INTO   :new.ID 
            FROM   dual; 
            END ADRESSE_ID_TR;\
```

My workaround is adding a  in  in db-changelog.xml.
I don't like it because the db-changelog.xml is going to be very large and I want it in the .sql files not in db-changelog.xml.

Another problem is when I generate DDL's with tools like Oracle SQL Developer and paste them in, they don't work. A lot of sql's don't work, probably not supported. I spend a lot of time testing my SQL's and Liquibase with Eclipse to fix the SQL's.
Any tips or will you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That syntax looks correct.  The endDelimiter should be telling it to override the default ; delimiter and use / instead.  What version of liquibase are you using?  Does it help if you put the \ not by itself?

```
  create or replace trigger Trig1 ...
  ...
  end Trig1; /

  create or replace trigger Trig2 ...
  ...
  end Trig2; /

  ...etc.
```

Comment: With '/' as separator there are problems with C-style comments (/*...*/), dates (10/10/2011) and the like. See http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/oracle-end-delimiter-issue